# Why does Heroku show more rows in DB after transfer?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm in the process of upgrading from the Heroku Bamboo stack to the Cedar stack. I'm following these [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration) for the upgrade and [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrate-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups) for doing the Postgres transfers.

I took a snapshot of DB_1, and then did a restore of it to DB_2. Then, to check that everything went well, I ran `heroku pg:info` on both apps, and it showed that DB_1 has 7494 rows, while DB_2 has 7772 rows.

Why are there nearly 300 more rows in DB_2, even though it was a *direct copy* of the data from DB_1 with no changes?

I tried `heroku restart` but the condition remains. According to `pg:info` DB_1 is running `Postgres 9.1.9` and DB_2 is running `Postgres 9.2.4`, I don't know if that makes a difference.

I also tried running this SQL query, and it also reported a different number of rows in DB_1 from DB_2:

```
 SELECT sum(reltuples) from pg_class where relname IN (SELECT c.relname
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
 LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
 WHERE c.relkind = 'r'
 AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
 AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
 AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
 AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is probably using statistical sampling from the PostgreSQL pg_stat tables to estimate row counts, so it won't be an exact match for the databases's current exact rowcount.

An ANALYZE, possibly after increasing `default_statistics_target`, might change the reported results.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear. It's not just Heroku that reports a different result, the SQL query I ran in the console also reports that DB_1 and DB_2 have different row counts. Shouldn't that query give an accurate number of rows?

Comment: @John No, `reltuples` is created by statistical sampling. If you want the true, current and exact rowcount you need to use a PL/PgSQL procedure that generates a `count(*) from the_table`, `EXECUTE`s the query for each table and sums the results. This will be slow as it'll require a full seqscan of every table. See the docs on `pg_catalog.pg_class`.